# error: ContentType matching query does not exist

Tags: django

In Django 1.3 doesn't work next example:

```
    try:
        object = ContentType.objects.get(model="test").get_object_for_this_type(pk=object_id)
     except:
        raise Http404
```

Why ?

Comment: If you weren't blindly swallowing the exception, the error message would tell you why.

Answer (score 3):

TO have django create `ContentType` for all your models, you should run

```
python manage.py syncdb
```